# How can I resolve google wrong synonom understanding in queries

Tags: seo, query-string, google-panda-algorithm

When someone specificies my site name (which isn't a dictionary word) in a search query, I would expect it to be very easy to be ranked at the top of the search results, and up until recently that was the case. Suddenly, google has started to do some sort of query expansions, which aren't even correct. For example

[image]

As you can see he highlights the word "Instagram" although it wasn't stated in the query and it isn't even that relevant, and very far from being a synonym to my sitename.

I've read that

> Historically, we have bolded synonyms such as stemming variants — like
>   the word "picture" for a search with the word "pictures." Now, we've
>   extended this to words that our algorithms very confidently think mean
>   the same thing, even if they are spelled nothing like the original
>   term.

But this just seems wrong. What can I do to resolve this or help Google learn better next time?

Answer (score 1):

*Twtrland being associated with Instagram*

It would seem that Google is treating twtrland as a shared word for instagram. This regularly happens on millions of searches, for example the word Rubbish is treated as the same as 'rubble, waste, trash, garbage' but this isn't limited to words that mean the same meaning... Like Google associates `Rubbish Removal` the same as `Waste Clearance` which can be different meanings.

*Associating words with words that have different meanings*

Another example of a word that is associated but with different meanings is the word 'tweet', a tweet isn't twitter but rather a function/feature of twitter but both are associated with one another because of the way people talk about twitter and tweet is often mentioned along side it.

*Authority and Rankings*

So because you are heavily linking out to instragram and have thousands of pages with both twtrland and instragram on the same page it's associated them with one another, and the reason why Stack Exchange appears top is because of the sheer amount of authority they have.

*Resolving the issue*

I don't see the problem with the two being associated with one another but rather see the issue with rankings. If you look further down the page you can see the right results are being displayed but rather not being at the top which would mean in 'time' your rankings will improve and your gain more authority for the associated keywords, of course lots quality relevant back-links will speed up this process.

Comment: By the way dunno if you noticed but it seems that you have 2x `</body></html>` happening and over a 100 fails on validation on W3C, a lot of minors but some majors that 'could' be creating problems on page renders. Thought I'd mention it ;)

Comment: Instagram isn't so really tighly associated with the site, and definitely much less associated than twitter for example which isn't highlighted in the results. I'm pretty sure this change happened recently (panda 4 release) and has caused significant changes in rankings.

Comment: Panda wouldn't make Instagram be 'BOLD' .... if its in bold its associated as a variant and is a keyword match (BOLD = Keyword match).. Hence my answer. We wouldn't be having this decusion if your site was top 'with the same search' hence why I said about authority.... Stack Overflow is within the TOP 100 sites in the WORLD.. so Google is returning a site that it believes it has 3 keyword matches (Instagram, Stack and Overflow), try the same search with a site not so mega in authority and the likehood is that your site will return as 'TOP'.

Comment: Using stack was actually just an example I thought was nice here. It highlights Instagram everywhere, and doesn't do the same for a much more relevant term like twitter (or any other term I've noticed). You don't find that odd?

Comment: Nope, Google does stupid stuff all the time... If this is a recent problem I'd imagine it reverts back. I see Google do plenty of silly stuff all the time, like for one phrase Monday to Thursday my customer site ranks #1 because of Google places and local rankings, but Friday - Sunday local search results are disabled on that keyword search and this has been occurring for 6months ;|

Comment: Do you have another example of the 'Twtrland keyword' search.

Comment: You can try a simple name search and see the Instagram highlighted. Like https://www.google.com/search?q=twtrland+Dylan&oq=twtrland+Dylan&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.450j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15123/discussion-between-noam-and-bybe).